# Calling overloaded function with an array parameter and a non-array parameter

Tags: c++, arrays, overloading, overload-resolution

I have this overloaded functions:

```
CString TestFunction(CString s, int number, int optPar1 = 123, int optPar2 = 456) //...
CString TestFunction(int index, CString s, int numbers[], int optPar1 = 123, int optPar2 = 456) //...
CString TestFunction(CString s, int numbers[], int optPar1 = 123, int optPar2 = 456) //...
```

When I do this:

1st case:

```
CString s = TestFunction(someString, anArrayOfIntsWithValues);
```

2nd case:

```
for (int i =0; i < max; i++)
{
    CString s = TestFunction(i, someString, anArrayOfIntsWithValues);
}
```

It gives me:

On the 1st case:

```
error C2664: 'CString Class1::TestFunction(CString, int, int, int)' : cannot convert parameter 2 from 'const int [2]' to 'int'
    5   IntelliSense: no instance of overloaded function "Class1::TestFunction" matches the argument list
```

On the 2nd case:

```
Error   2   error C2664: 'CString Class1::TestFunction(CString, int,int,int)' : cannot convert parameter 1 from 'int' to 'CString'
6   IntelliSense: no instance of overloaded function "Class1::TestFunction" matches the argument list
```

I am new to C++ and I don't know what is wrong with this code, but it was perfectly compiled in C# (with the knowledge of overloaded functions and optional parameters).

*Note: this is just a representation of the real code - user-defined types are used as parameters.*

**EDIT: added a second case and 1st case was already answered.**

Comment: Note that using `[]` in parameter list is archaic and actually the array is not passed by value . So this may differ from your expectations if you are coming from other languages

Answer (score 2):

At first, the parameter declaration `int numbers[]` is same as `int* numbers` in fact. Then,

`anArrayOfIntsWithValues` is an array of `const int`, i.e. `const int[2]`; which could decay to `const int*`, but can't be implicitly converted to both `int` and `int*`, then calling failed.

If you want the 2nd overload to be invoked, you can change the type of `anArrayOfIntsWithValues` to `int [2]`, or change the type of parameter `numbers` to `const int[]` (or `const int*`), to make them match.